# Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) in React.js Project deployed

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

When I deploy my react project into Surge, the build is successful and can get the app URL.
But when I link to the URL, I can see one blank page and some bunch of errors in the inspect console:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) 3.138a0231.chunk.css
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) main.bd0d3f99.chunk.js:1
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) main.bd0d3f99.chunk.css:1
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) manifest.json:1
Manifest: Line: 1, column: 1, Syntax error. manifest.json:1 
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) 3.138a0231.chunk.css
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) 3.138a0231.chunk.css
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) main.bd0d3f99.chunk.css:1
```

Here is the react start script in my `package.json` file.

```
"scripts": {
  "build": "REACT_APP_BACKEND=true PUBLIC_URL='/sing-app-react' node scripts/build.js",
  "start": "node scripts/start.js",
  "start:backend": "REACT_APP_BACKEND=true node scripts/start.js",
  "test": "node scripts/test.js"
},
```

And the link address to css file that causes the erros `https://lopsided-dinner.surge.sh/sing-app-react/static/css/3.138a0231.chunk.css`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`https://lopsided-dinner.surge.sh/sing-app-react/static/css/3.138a0231.chunk.css`

This website url built by react script should be something like `https://your domain/static/css...`

Remove the PUBLIC_URL in your build script and run build again.

It leads the build source to /static/....

Hopefully that makes sense to you!

Comment: Cool! That's the problem that the site didn't reach to the css and style files because of the ```/sing-app-react/``` inside the link.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the issue was I was serving my react project from a `build` folder and there was `/build` in `.gitignore` file. I removed `/build` from .gitignore file and it worked