# How can I deploy my React app in a regular host?

Tags: reactjs

I created a web app in React and now i'm trying to deploy it on a host.
I ran `npm run build` from the command line.
I copied files from the 'build' folder that is created and uploaded them in my host's folder (public_html/app).

but I only see a white screen in my mydomain.com/app or mydomain.com/app/index.html

[image]

Ok, now is working... after create a .htaccess file and also add the 'homepage' value in the package.json file.

But I can't see my jsx components.
I only see the app.js contents

My index.js looks like this:

```
import { createRoot } from 'react-dom/client';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';


const container = document.getElementById('root');
const root = createRoot(container);
root.render(<App tab="home" />);

reportWebVitals();
```

app.js

```
  return (
    <div className="app-container">
      <header className="app-header">
        <img src={logo} className="logo-header" alt='logo' />
        <Router>
            <Routes>
              <Route index element={<Register />} />
              <Route path="/Login" caseSensitive={false} element={<Login />} />
              <Route path="/Register" caseSensitive={false} element={<Register />} />
              <Route path='/Profile' caseSensitive={false} element={<Profile />} />
              <Route path='/Formrdo' caseSensitive={false} element={<Formrdo />} />
              <Route path='/Setup' caseSensitive={false} element={<Setup />} />
              <Route path='/ResetPassword' caseSensitive={false} element={<ResetPassword />} />
            </Routes>
        </Router>
      </header>
```

package.json

[image]

.htaccess

````
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
  RewriteRule . /index.html [L]

</IfModule>```
````

Comment: Consult browser's console to see what errors you get

Comment: I get: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()
4 times

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) in React.js Project deployed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60271280/failed-to-load-resource-the-server-responded-with-a-status-of-404-not-found-i)

Comment: Yes I fixed that part and now i can see the app but i can't see all my components (jsx) @palindrom

Comment: if you are using create-react-app <https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment/>,

Comment: please provide your project configuration in your question

Comment: You have to change base url from index.html Ref: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45208595/setting-base-href-using-environment-variables

Comment: @simo54 what configuration?

Comment: @AakashRathee yes, I'm using create-react-app and I followed the docs. But i can't fix that...

Comment: my bad. I meant previously to share your files configuration such as package.json, webpack file if there is any, etc etc. There are many missing informations in your question that prevent the viewers to see what's causing the issue.